# how to reject http request in expressjs app?

Tags: javascript, express

My app has to load some data into memory at beginning of the program.  I'd like to reject any request until all the data is loaded.  What is the approach that I can use in expressjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might put `app.listen` into a callback that's run on completion for whatever data it is you're loading, instead of checking on a per-request basis. expressjs will not respond to any requests before `app.listen` is called.